# Storing statistics as JSON in a simulation game

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, iteration, scope

I am working on a choice-based simulation and players have to choose between different locations, I am pushing those choices to an array `locationLog` and my `MakeStats()` function below builds an array from it. I tend to break code into bits because it helps me, but want to make sure others can understand it.

```
var hasAttorney = false;
var hasMoney = true;
var hasAC = true;
var currentlocation = "home";
var locationLog = []; //push locations

//Builds a JSON object with game stats
function MakeStats() {
    let home = 0,
        motel = 0,
        relative = 0,
        shelter = 0,
        apartment = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < locationLog.length; i++) {
        if (locationLog[i] === "home")
            home++;
        else if (locationLog[i] === "motel")
            motel++;
        else if (locationLog[i] === "relative")
            relative++;
        else if (locationLog[i] === "shelter")
            shelter++;
        else if (locationLog[i] === "apartment")
            apartment++;
    }

    let tempJSON = {
        "location": {
            "home": home,
            "motel": motel,
            "relative": relative,
            "shelter": shelter,
            "apartment": apartment
        },
        "moneyLeft": money,
        "ACLeft": AC,
        "finalDestination": currentlocation,
        "hasAttorney": hasAttorney,
        "hasAC": hasAC,
        "hasMoney": hasMoney
    };
    statJSON = tempJSON;
    localStorage.setItem("playerStats", JSON.stringify(statJSON));
    console.log(statJSON);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code review! Some variables are declared in that function but others are not - e.g. `AC`, `money`, `locationLog`, etc. Where are those defined? Can you update the code sample to provide sample values for those?

Comment: updated the variables, the JSON works just fine.

Comment: okay I am guessing `money` is declared something like `var money = 0` and `AC` something like `var AC = 0`;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Feedback

#### Simplifying block of `if` statements

The set of `if` statements is a bit repetitive, especially since the values match the property names of the nested JSON object that is stored in `localStorage`. A simpler way to implement this would be to declare `tempJSON` first, with the nested location values at `0`, then iterate through `locationLog` and increment the appropriate nested value. One can use [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
if (tempJSON.location.hasOwnProperty(locationLog[i])) {
    tempJSON.location[locationLog[i]]++;
```

Or use the `in` operator:

```
if (locationLog[i] in tempJSON.location) {
    tempJSON.location[locationLog[i]]++;
```

Both will work the same. For the discussion of the difference, see answers to [*if (key in object) or if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)* on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13632999/1575353).

#### Iterating over `locationLog`

Since your code is using [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like `let`, it can also utilize the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop construct instead of setting up variable `i` and using it to index into the array.

```
for (const location of locationLog) {
    if (location in tempJSON.location) {
```

#### Default to using `const` for variables to avoid unintentional re-assignment

Variables that should not be re-assigned, like `tempJSON` can be declared with [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `let`. If you determine later that re-assignment should be allowed (e.g. in a loop or conditional expression) then use `let`.

#### variable `statJSON`

That may be a global variable or else you just didn't include the local declaration (and assignment) but if it is a global variable then consider making it a local variable. In the scope of the code you included, it appears superfluous...

### Rewritten code

See the snippet below utilizing the feedback above.

```js
var hasAttorney = false;
var hasMoney = true;
var money = 0;
var AC = 1;
var hasAC = true;
var currentlocation = "home";
var locationLog = ["relative", "shelter", "relative"]; //push locations

//Builds a JSON object with game stats
function MakeStats() {
    const tempJSON = {
        "location": {
            "home": 0,
            "motel": 0,
            "relative": 0,
            "shelter": 0,
            "apartment": 0
        },
        "moneyLeft": money,
        "ACLeft": AC,
        "finalDestination": currentlocation,
        "hasAttorney": hasAttorney,
        "hasAC": hasAC,
        "hasMoney": hasMoney
    };
    for (const location of locationLog) {
      if (location in tempJSON.location) {
        tempJSON.location[location]++;
      }
    }
    
    //localStorage not allowed in SE snippets for security reasons
    //localStorage.setItem("playerStats", JSON.stringify(tempJSON));
    console.log(tempJSON);
}
MakeStats();
```

Comment: much better, just getting acquainted with ES6. It's a bit weird an object with const lets you update values.

Comment: Yes - "_The **`const` declaration** creates a read-only reference to a value. It does **not** mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned._" - [MDN documentation for `const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description)

Comment: `for (let location of locationLog)` could be `for (const location of locationLog)` if `location` is not going to be reassigned

Comment: Good on ya! [the documentation on MDN even says so](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Examples) ... but then the subsequent examples about iterating over a string use `let` though the value isn't reassigned inside the loop block- SERENITY NOW!! Maybe I should edit those examples

Answer (score 3):

Some extra points that Sam Onᴇᴌᴀ's good review skipped.

### Capitalizing function names

Don't capitalize functions if they are not used to create an object. In JavaScript we only capitalize functions or objects that can be instantiated with the `new` token. Thus `MakeStats` should be `makeStats`.

However if you were to return the object `statJSON` then you could use the name `MakeStats` to indicate that it instantiates an object. You can then create the object in 3 ways, each of which return the same object.

```
    // last 2 lines of MakeStats to be
    return statJSON;
}

const s1 = new MakeStats();
const s2 = new MakeStats;  // with new objects () is not needed if there are no arguments
const s3 = MakeStats();
```

### Quoted property names

I see this a lot, when people create an object that is to be stringified. For some reason  quoted property names are used. Doing so is just adding unneeded noise to the code.

The only time you need to use quotes to define a property is if the property is not a valid javascript variable name. e.g.  `{data-one: "one"}` will throw an error as `data-one` is not a valid name, you would thus write it `{"data-one": "one"}`

### Shorthand property names (ES2015)

Use object property shorthand if you are adding existing named variables to an object.

You have

```
let tempJSON = {
    "location": {
        "home": home,
        "motel": motel,
        "relative": relative,
        "shelter": shelter,
        "apartment": apartment
    },
    "moneyLeft": money,
    "ACLeft": AC,
    "finalDestination": currentlocation,
    "hasAttorney": hasAttorney,
    "hasAC": hasAC,
    "hasMoney": hasMoney
};
```

can be written as

```
const tempJSON = {
    location: {home, motel, relative, shelter, apartment},
    moneyLeft: money,
    ACLeft: AC,
    finalDestination: currentlocation,
    hasAttorney, 
    hasAC,
    hasMoney
};
```

the resulting object is identical to the longhand version.

### `localStorage`

You can use simpler notation when accessing `localStorage`.

You have

```
localStorage.setItem("playerStats", JSON.stringify(statJSON));
```

is identical to

```
localStorage.playerStats = JSON.stringify(statJSON);
```

The same applies to reading from `localStorage`

```
stats = localStorage.playerStats; // Note If that data is not there you get undefined
                                  // Note All data from local storage is a string
```

### Don't trust `localStorage`

There is no way to guarantee that `localStorage` content written in one session will be available next time, nor can you trust the data you read back, and many 3rd party extensions have full access to `localStorage`.

If the data is important, requires trust, or contains personal client data it should be saved on the server.

### Warning about cyclic data

`JSON.stringify` will throw a `TypeError: "Converting circular structure to JSON"` if the data contains cyclic references.

Cyclic references are everywhere in JavaScript so if you are stringifying data from unknown or unsure sources is pays to wrap the `stringify` in a `try` `catch` so at least you can recover gracefully. As your function is using data from outside its control it would pay to be safe (unless you are in full control of all data).

Comment: `Don't capitalize functions if they are not used to create an object. In JavaScript we only capitalize functions or objects that can be instantiated with the new token.` I considered Modifying the second sentence to begin "In _idiomatic_ JavaScript..." but am not sure what you would want.... it may be wise to mention conventions/style guides there...